# Evitar bloqueo de pantalla en Android y VR

Tags: android, unity, vr

Estoy programando un apk de VR con Unity pero me surge el siguiente problema.

Al tratarse de una aplicación de VR no tengo contacto ninguno con la pantalla táctil de mi móvil, por lo tanto a los 10 segundos se atenua la pantalla y 5 segundos más tarde se bloquea.

Quisiera saber qué solución le puedo dar a esto sin tener que desactivar el bloqueo de pantalla desde el móvil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar [`sleepTimeout`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-sleepTimeout.html):

```
Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
```

Para evitar que se bloquee el móvil.

Si tuvieras algún problema, añade esto al manifiest para los permisos:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba mantener la pantalla siempre encendida con este método

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

dentro de tu actividad, llamalo en algún método que requiera hacer aplicar esto, y una vez que termine, puedes retirarlo con este metodo.

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_‌​SCREEN_ON)
```

Espero te funcione.